# Automatically using self signed SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I'm creating a launcher for a game I'm making. To gain access to the launcher's menu the user has to first create an account on the game's site, buy the game using it, and then login to the launcher using his credentials. I've set up a php script on the server which accepts a username and password MD5 hash parameter (in the URL), checks to see if the account is in the database and returns relevant information to the launcher.

Since I'm transferring sensitive (albeit encrypted) information over the Internet I've figured that using SSL would be the best way to go about doing this. Since I can't quite afford a legit third party signed certificate I've signed one myself. It's bundled in the launcher and added to the trust store programmatically so that I can use it to connect to that php script and login without any problems.

Now this whole system I've described works just fine, but I've heard from someone that using a self signed SSL certificate without the user's consent is illegal in some countries (namely Denmark, maybe others). I've tried looking this up to see whether I should add some sort of confirmation dialog to the launcher but I couldn't find anything.

I'm located (and developing the program) in Israel, the server is in the Netherlands.

Does anyone know what laws my friend was talking about, and what I should do to avoid breaking them, as well as online sources where I can read more about them?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about law, not code.

Answer (score 1):

Some countries have laws against using encryption. Check out [Crypto Law Survey](http://cryptolaw.org) for details on each countries' restrictions. The Netherlands appears to have some restrictions, if so, you might want to consider moving your server.